# Cycle through subdirectory in google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a storage bucket in google cloud. I have a few directories which I created with files in them.

I know that if I want to cycle through all the files in one of the directories, I can use the following command:

```
for file in list(source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix='subdir/subdir2')):
    file_path=f"gs://{file.bucket.name}/{file.name}"
    print(file_path)
```

However, the result includes the actual path that I am trying to cycle through,

```
gs://bucket-name/subdir/subdir2 <----- this item
gs://bucket-name/subdir/subdir2/file1
gs://bucket-name/subdir/subdir2/file2
....
```

Is there a way to cycle through the directory without having the directory appear so that it looks like this.

```
gs://bucket-name/subdir/subdir2/file1
gs://bucket-name/subdir/subdir2/file2
....
```

I managed to do this:

```
subdir = 'subdir1/subdir2/'

for file in list(source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=subdir)):
    file_path = f"gs://{file.bucket.name}/{file.name}"
    if file.name == subdir:
        continue
    else:
        print(file_path)
```

But is there a cleaner way to do it using the google storage api? I tried to look up the documentation but I don't see anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage does not actually have directories, it is a flat structure. The Console is just making it look like a hierarchical structure by naming the objects with a pattern similar to a file system. So when you request all the objects in a specific "folder" you are just requesting all objects that start with the same prefix, thus you are getting the entire "sub-hierarchy" as a result.

You can check https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects for more information. This is the relevant bit:

> Object names reside in a flat namespace within a bucket. This means
>   that:
>
> ```
> Different buckets can have objects with the same name.
> Objects do not reside within subdirectories in a bucket.
> ```
>
> For example, you can name an object /europe/france/paris.jpg to make
>   it appear that paris.jpg resides in the subdirectory /europe/france,
>   but to Cloud Storage, the object simply exists in the bucket and has
>   the name /europe/france/paris.jpg. As a result, while deeply nested,
>   directory-like structures using slash delimiters are possible within
>   Cloud Storage, they don't have the performance that a native
>   filesystem has when listing deeply nested sub-directories.

Comment: What Ville said. If you're looking for a more structured file system type storage, you could take a peek at Filestore which has more convention around behaving more like a file system.